# Create work order subfolders to track projects

Tags: excel, vba

I work with Excel to keep track of my projects. I receive multiple work orders in a project. I need to create multiple folders within the project folder.

I worked out a macro to create folders based on work order numbers but I need subfolders within the work order folders.

The subfolders remain constant, being Input & Output folders.
Folder structure goes as Project folder>Work order>Input & Output.

```vb
Sub Create_Folders()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
Dim path As Variant

Set Rng = Selection

maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

For c = 1 To maxCols
    r = 1

    path = Application.InputBox("Enter the path where you want to create the folders", "Enter location")

    Do While r <= maxRows

        If Len(Dir(path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir (path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
            On Error Resume Next
        End If

        r = r + 1
    Loop
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget that you need to use the [tag:vba] tag, else you may be missing out on the audience you are actually trying to reach. Also, in your line `Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer`, only `c` is being declared as type **Integer**. The rest are type **Variant**. You must append `As <Type>` to each variable declaration.

Comment: One way you could fix your above issue is to use the `%` declaration. `%`, when used as a type declaration, can replace `As Integer`. So `Dim a%, b%, c%, d As Integer` would all be typed as **Integer**. `$` is string, `&` is long, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim path As Variant, fpath$
'...
fpath = path & Application.PathSeparator & Rng(r, c).Text
If Len(Dir(fpath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
  MkDir fpath 'create main folder
  'create subfolders
  MkDir fpath & Application.PathSeparator & "Input"
  MkDir fpath & Application.PathSeparator & "Output"
  '...
End If
```